# Extracting subset from fasta file

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file which looks like this:

```
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chrUn
ACGTGGATATTT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
>chrUn5
TGATAGCTGTTG
```

I just want to extract `chr1`, `chr2`, `chr21`, `chrX` along with their sequences. So the output I want is:

```
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

How can I do it in unix command line?

Comment: Is that example representative or do you have the entire chromosome sequence there? The solutions will be completely different for one-line sequences and for multiline sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^>chr1$\|^>chr2$\|^>chr21$\|^>chrX$/{p;n;p}' file
```

- `-n` suppresses automatic output.
- `/.../` the regular expression to match `>chr1`, `>chr2`, `>chr21` or `>chrX`.
- `{p;n;p}` if the expression matches, print the line, read the next input line to pattern space, and print that line too.

---

If it must be `awk`, it's nearly the same mechanism:

```
awk '/^>chr1$|^>chr2$|^>chr21$|^>chrX$/{print;getline;print;}' file
```

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned this, but FASTA files often (usually) have more than a single line under the `>id`. Your solution works perfectly for the OP's example (so +1), but will probably fail on their actual data.

Answer (score 10):

For the simple example you show, where all sequences fit on a single line, you could just use `grep` (if your `grep` doesn't support the `--no-group-separator` option, pass the output through `grep -v -- '--'`):

```
$ grep -wEA1 --no-group-separator 'chr1|chr2|chr21|chrX' file.fa 
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

Assuming you have multi-line sequences (which seems likely if you're dealing with chromosomes), you will need to concatenate them into one line first. This complicates things considerably. You could use an `awk` one-liner:

```
$ awk -vRS=">" 'BEGIN{t["chr1"]=1;t["chr2"]=1;t["chr21"]=1;t["chrX"]=1}
                {if($1 in t){printf ">%s",$0}}' file.fa
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

The script above sets the record separator to `>` (`vRS=">"`). This means that "lines" are defined by `>~` and not `\n`. Then, the `BEGIN` block sets up an array where each of the target sequence IDs is a key. The rest simply checks each "line" (sequence) and, if the 1st field is in the array (`$i in t`), it prints the current "line" (`$0`) preceded by a `>`.

If you're going to be doing this sort of thing often, writing up the array will quickly become annoying. Personally, I use the two scripts below, which I inherited from a former lab mate, to convert FASTA to tbl format (`sequence_name<TAB>sequence`,one sequence per line) and back:

- `FastaToTbl`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/awk -f
  {
          if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
          if (NR>1)
                      printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
          else 
              printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
          else 
                  printf "%s", $0
  }END{printf "\n"}
  ```
- `TblToFasta`

  ```
  #! /usr/bin/awk -f
  {
    sequence=$NF

    ls = length(sequence)
    is = 1
    fld  = 1
    while (fld < NF)
    {
       if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
       printf "%s " , $fld
       if (fld == NF-1){
          printf "\n"
        }
        fld = fld+1
    }
    while (is <= ls){
      printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
      is=is+60
    }
  }
  ```

If you save those in your `$PATH` and make them executable, you can simply `grep` for your target sequences (and this will work for multi-line sequences, unlike the above):

```
$ FastaToTbl file.fa | grep -wE 'chr1|chr2|chr21|chrX' | TblToFasta
>chr1 
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2 
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21 
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX 
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

This is much easier to extend since you can pass `grep` a file of search targets:

```
$ cat ids.txt 
chr1
chr2
chr21
chrX

$ FastaToTbl file.fa | grep -wFf ids.txt | TblToFasta
>chr1 
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2 
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21 
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX 
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

---

Finally, if you will be working with large sequences, you might consider getting one of the various tools that can do this sort of thing for you. They will be far faster and more efficient in the long run. For example, `fastafetch` from the [`exonerate`](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/about/vertebrate-genomics/software/exonerate) suite. It is available in the repos of most Linux distributions. On Debian based systems you can install it with `sudo apt-get install exonerate`, for example. Once you've installed it, you can do:

```
## Create the index    
fastaindex -f file.fa -i file.in
## Loop and retrieve your sequences
for seq in chr1 chr2 chr21 chrX; do
     fastafetch -f file.fa -i file.in -q "$seq" 
done 
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

Alternatively, you can use my own [`retrieveseqs.pl`](https://github.com/terdon/scripts/blob/master/retrieveseqs.pl), which has a few other nifty functions:

```
$ retrieveseqs.pl -h

    retrieveseqs.pl will take one or more lists of ids and extract their sequences from 
    multi FASTA file

    USAGE : retrieveseqs.pl [-viofsn] <FASTA sequence file> <desired IDs, one per line>

    -v : verbose output, print a progress indicator (a "." for every 1000 sequences processed)
    -V : as above but a "!" for every desired sequence found.
    -f : fast, takes first characters of name "(/^([^\s]*)/)" given until the first space as the search string
         make SURE that those chars are UNIQUE.
    -i : use when the ids in the id file are EXACTLY identical
         to those in the FASTA file
    -h : Show this help and exit.
    -o : will create one fasta file for each of the id files
    -s : will create one fasta file per id
    -n : means that the last arguments (after the sequence file)
         passed are a QUOTED list of the names desired.
    -u : assumes uniprot format ids (separated by |)
```

In your case, you would do:

```
$ retrieveseqs.pl -fn file.fa "chr1 chr2 chr21 chrX"
[7 (4/4 found]
>chr1
ACGGTGTAGTCG
>chr2
ACGTGTATAGCT
>chr21
ACGTTGATGAAA
>chrX
GTACGGGGGTGG
```

Note that this was something I wrote for my own work and it isn't very well documented or supported. Still, I've been using it happily for years.

Comment: Recent versions of GNU grep have a `--no-group-separator` context line option that does away with the need for the additional `grep -v -- '--'` when using `grep -An`

Comment: @steeldriver ah, thanks. I actually read through `man grep` before posting since I remembered something like that but didn't manage to find it. It doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in my Arch's `man grep` (only in the `info` page).

Comment: Yes same on my Ubuntu box (14.04 w/ grep v.2.16) - only in the info page

Comment: In `fastafetch` in `exonerate version 2.4.0` there is `-F` option which reads IDs from file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, the retrieveseqs.pl is great, but slower than a similar program I have used for years by John Nash.  I cannot find it online, but we have it on our github (https://github.com/NCGAS/Useful-Scripts/blob/master/subset_fasta.pl)

```
[xxxxx@h1 test2]$ time ../retrieveseqs.pl cdna.cds.predupclean cds.list >tmp
[3926 (3925/3925 found]
real    0m17.622s
user    0m17.102s
sys     0m0.045s

[xxxxx@h1 test2]$ time ../subset_fasta.pl -i cdna.list < cdna.cds.predupclean > tmp
real    0m3.111s
user    0m2.987s
sys     0m0.032s
```

EDIT: out of curiosity, I also tested the TableToFasta method, which seems to be faster than both above:

```
[xxxxx@c71 test2]$ time ./FastaToTable cdna.cds.predupclean | grep -wFf <(sed 's/>//g' cdna.list) | ./TableToFasta > tmp
real    0m0.189s
user    0m0.222s
sys     0m0.047s
```

Comment: To test the speed of the retrieveseqs.pl script, you should use the -f flag since that speeds it up enormously.